# Hash index is taking 1000% more time than Btree in postgres

Tags: postgresql

Is there anyway we can improve the Hash index creation as it is taking more time than Btree

Comment: Why do you think you need a hash index to begin with? They typically don't really offer a benefit over a B-Tree index

Comment: Why do you need it?

Comment: As I have only 3 unique records for 100 million records. Thus thinking HASH algorithm work better? Am I wrong here? @a_horse_with_no_name/@frank